# Debugging CSS page overflow

Tags: html, css, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

My [page](http://wishes.info/wedding) is overflowing to the right (there is extra empty space causing a horizontal scrollbar). CSS file is [link to css](http://wishes.info/css/all.css).

The practice I have followed is - in the beginning, setting padding & margin 0 for all used html elements. Then, the top level boxes have width+padding+margin <= 100% to the best of my observation. More importantly, I have debugged in Chrome Developer Tools and Firebug (in Firefox). I went through each container box in the hierarchy in body tag, and each one's width is same as window width. Why then the overflow?

On a related note,  if div A contains  divs B & C, then A's width will be at least max(width(B), width(C)), right?

Comment: Because you have a responsive site- you can add `overflow:hidden` to `body`...however that doesnt address the underling issue

Comment: You can quickly debug this type of problem by deleting elements off the page with Chrome's inspector (click an element in the inspector, press delete key on keyboard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is on `#mainhmenu` with 100% width and 5% padding on boths sides from

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
  #navigation ul {
  padding: 0% 5%;
}
```

contributing to an overall width of 110%.

Comment: Need to either adjust the width, padding, add `overflow-x` hidden to `body`,  or I'd recommend moving forward with `box-sizing: border-box;` http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Thanks Evan for actually narrowing down it. I learnt something good from answers by you and others today.

Comment: Glad it helped ~ Everyone has their own method for narrowing down bugs. Good luck moving forward!

Answer (score 2):

I just released a cross browser tool that you can use to solve problems like this.  Just mouseover each element in the area to see margins, borders and padding until you find the culprit!

[HTML Box Visualizer - GitHub](https://github.com/ghmcadams/boxvis)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width: 100%;` from `#mainhmenu` :)

Comment: Firstly, thanks! Now I went down to that level of hierarchy and indeed it is the cause of overflow. My curiosity is - how to find such issues in general? Shouldn't mainhmenu's parents have width more than mainhmenu? Or basically in debugging tools that is not the case and one has to check each and every element individually?

Comment: Personally I delete nodes one by one, and if something is causing a problem I'm trying to modify CSS values.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I did. Opened up inspector and started working from the bottom up - deleting nodes until whatever the issue is can be narrowed down.

Answer (score 1):

Its your #mainmenu
Its width is set at 100% and has a 5% padding on the sides. 
If you get rid of the padding or set its width to 90% you will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the horizontal scrollbar by,

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

hope this helps.And please do understand that once you specify a width and if you add padding to it, it will add to the overall width of the element.